# Setting a StackOverflow community twitter-like service?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, twitter

Hey,
Why not having a microblogging service for not-that-meaningful questions or updates?

Like, right now I'd like to ask 'wtf python.org is down?'. I have eventually found the answer by searching on search.twitter.com but I do think the StackOverflow community is just amazing and I'd love to use such a microblogging service.

Comment: Lucky you have one rep because the outcome of this won't be good

Comment: Pointing out that sites are down at a particular point (5 mins, an hour, a day?) in time is best left to twitter or http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ :)

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is not a social networking site. It's not going to become a social networking site. Jeff has been pretty clear on this.

Listen to the [latest podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-64/) (1:00:52):

> **Jeff:** ... I kind of like having control over what I think the
> product is and what we're building and the direction of it, and I don't want
> to be pulled in like ten different directions in terms of "Hey let's make it
> a social networking site" - that would be like a horror story for me - that's
> everything I don't want, right? But if you open source, somebody could fork you
> and say "You know what, I'm going to make the ultra-social Facebook version of Stack Overflow" - I'm getting an ulcer just thinking about this actually - where you can friend people and, you know, you can send little private messages to each other and it's all about *hanging out* and *being buddies* - it's horrible!

> **Joel:** Don't give 'em any ideas.

I understand that what you're asking for isn't *quite* that, but it's pretty darned close - and would almost certainly be *used* in that way, even if it was really designed for just time-sensitive quick programming-related questions/updates.

Nope, I can't see this happening...

Comment: earlier today there was a question on StackOverflow about programmers diet, it was closed and I can understand why but I do think StackOverflow could have a place for such topics

Comment: @Saggi: It *could*, but it *shouldn't*.

Comment: @Saggi: If you want to set up a StackExchange server for such things then go ahead when it's released... but it sounds like the amount of interesting content vs noise would be pretty grim.

Answer (score 6):

If you want something twitter-like, use twitter.

'Nuf said.

Answer (score 3):

You want... *What* now?

If that Twitter thing is useful - and i'm not yet convinced it is - then just use it. What do you need SO for?

If Twitter doesn't do what you need, then why on earth would a SO-branded clone be any better?

Answer (score 1):

uh...if we wanted twitter-like clutter and noise, perhaps we'd...use twitter!